# Django ORM Show Latest Message of a conversation

Tags: sql, django

I am trying to get the latest text for each group

My model is:

```
class SampleMessaging(models.Model):
    receiver_id = models.IntegerField()
    sender_id = models.IntegerField()
    message = models.TextField()
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

This will be the output if I selected SampleGrouping.objects.all():

```
--------------------------------------------------------
id | sender_id|receiver_id|    message      | order
--------------------------------------------------------
1  |    1       |       1       | Hello World!  | 1
2  |    1       |       1       | Hello World2! | 2
3  |    2       |       1       | Hello World3! | 1
4  |    2       |       1       | Hello World4! | 2
5  |    1       |       2       | Hello World5! | 3
6  |    1       |       3       | Hi World!     | 1
7  |    1       |       3       | Hi World2!    | 2
8  |    1       |       3       | H i World3!   | 3
9  |    4       |       1       | Hi Hello!     | 1
10 |    4       |       1       | Hi Hello2!    | 2
11 |    4       |       1       | Hi Hello3!    | 3
12 |    5       |       1       | Gintama 1!    | 1
13 |    5       |       1       | Gintama 22!   | 2
14 |    1       |       6       | Sakata 1!     | 1
15 |    1       |       6       | Sakata 32!    | 2
16 |    1       |       5       | Gintama 256!  | 3
```

What I need is an ORM that will result to:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
id | sender_id  |     receiver_id   |    message    | order
---------------------------------------------------------------
5  |    1       |           2       | Hello World5! | 3
8  |    1       |           3       | H i World3!   | 3
11 |    4       |           1       | Hi Hello3!    | 3
16 |    1       |           5       | Gintama 256!  | 3
15 |    1       |           6       | Sakata 32!    | 2
```

Think of this model as a conversation table and what I want is to show all the latest message(determined by order) of each user conversation

Comment: Have you tried anything? It seems like you just need to order and slice the results  `SampleGrouping.objects.order_by('-order')[:5]`

Comment: That ORM is not what I'm looking for, I'm actually trying the GROUP BY

Comment: Your desired output looks more like ordering than grouping. If you want GROUP BY, it's not clear on what condition you are grouping. Could you explain more please?

Comment: I updated my question to make it a little bit more clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of better way than grouping by your data first

```
from django.db.models import Max, Q

filter_data = list(SampleMessaging.objects.all().values('sender_id', 'receiver_id').annotate(order=Max('order')).distinct())
```

And than combining it to multiple [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to filter by them like this

Fixing case in comments

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267554/filter-list-of-dicts-by-higest-value-of-dict-and-taking-reversed-values-into-acc/39267938#39267938 
result = {}
for item in filter_data:
    key = frozenset([item["sender_id"], item["receiver_id"]])
    if key not in result or result[key]["order"] < item["order"]:
        result[key] = item
qs_data = result.values()

# and now we can prepare our Q
qs_filter = Q(**qs_data[0])
for data in qs_data[1:]:
     qs_filter |= Q(**data)

desired_qs = SampleMessaging.objects.filter(qs_filter)
```

Note: this will work only if you can guarantee that combination of `sender_id`, `receiver_id` and `order` is unique.

**Bonus**
Wrap this into [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) method so it can be simply called like

```
SampleMessaging.objects.latest_messages()
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. Keep note that the latest message of each conversation. "receiver_id=1, sender_id=2" must be synced with "sender_id=1, receiver_id=2"

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada Is only thing not working correctly that I didn't get case you mentioned into account? If this will be fixed everything will be ok?

Comment: What I meant was, it's not returning the expected result. My bad for the "not working" part

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada I'm just curious is it working?