# Filter list of dicts by highest value of dict and taking reversed values into account

Tags: python

Let's say i have data looking like this:

```
filter_data = [
    {'sender_id': 1, 'receiver_id': 2, 'order': 1},
    {'sender_id': 2, 'receiver_id': 1, 'order': 3},
    {'sender_id': 3, 'receiver_id': 2, 'order': 5},
    {'sender_id': 2, 'receiver_id': 3, 'order': 2},
]

# there must be a better way to get max elements by reversed keys
# in list of dicts, but I think this whole another question
# so for now let this be this way. 
def get_data():
    qs_data = []
    for data in filter_data:
        for cmp_data in filter_data:
            if data['sender_id'] == cmp_data['receiver_id'] and\
                    data['receiver_id'] == cmp_data['sender_id']:
                if data['order'] > cmp_data['order']:
                    d = data
                else:
                    d = cmp_data
                if d not in qs_data:
                    qs_data.append(d)
    return qs_data
```

and desired output will be

```
[{'order': 3, 'receiver_id': 1, 'sender_id': 2},
 {'order': 5, 'receiver_id': 2, 'sender_id': 3}]
```

What my code does it filters `filter_data` so I will get list of items with highest value of `order` for `sender_id` and `receiver_id` but for me `receiver_id=1, sender_id=2` is same as `sender_id=1, receiver_id=2`

So my question is is there more pythonic/faster way to do this? Or may be can someone point to direction of improvement.

**P.S.** I would much appreciate if someone can come up with understandable title. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I'm trying my hardest but I just do not understand what you're asking

Comment: using list comprehension in python

Comment: @KalpeshDusane List comperhension is just a syntactic sugar. I don't get your suggestion. What I was asking is about maybe there are some functions in standard library that can make this code shorter and more readable

Comment: So, for each pair of sender and receiver, regardless of who is who, you want the highest order?

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum values of order for sender_id and receiver_id"?

Comment: Ah, I understand now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary, mapping a `frozenset` of sender and receiver ID (so order does not matter) to the item with the currently highest order.

```
result = {}
for item in filter_data:
    key = frozenset([item["sender_id"], item["receiver_id"]])
    if key not in result or result[key]["order"] < item["order"]:
        result[key] = item
```

Then, just extract the `values()` from the dictionary to get `[{'order': 3, 'receiver_id': 1, 'sender_id': 2}, {'order': 5, 'receiver_id': 2, 'sender_id': 3}]`

Or collect all the items, grouped by sender/receiver pair, and use a list comprehension with `max` to get those with the highest orders:

```
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item in filter_data:
    key = frozenset([item["sender_id"], item["receiver_id"]])
    result[key].append(item)
max_values = [max(lst, key=lambda x: x["order"]) for lst in result.values()]
```

Comment: Cool idea! Using combination of `sender` and `receiver` as keys.

Answer (score 1):

Did I understand you now?

```py
from itertools import groupby

grp = groupby(filter_data, lambda x: (min(x["sender_id"], x["receiver_id"]), max(x["sender_id"], x["receiver_id"])))
l = [sorted(g, key = lambda x: -x["order"])[0] for k, g in grp]
```

Comment: Note: For this to work, `filter_data` has to be sorted by the key to be grouped by. The order in a dictionary is more or less random, so it might work on the small example, but fail otherwise. Also, instead of `sorted(...)[0]`, why not use `max`?

Comment: You are right about that the data need to be sorted for the group by. Regarding why not using max - because we need to retrieve the item itself and not just the maximal order.

Comment: You can use the same `key` function you used for sorting for `max` (just remove the `-`): `max(g, key = lambda x: x["order"])`

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty dictionary that will gather the new highest dictionary. We iterate through your `filter_data` and check the sum of `sender_id` and `receiver_id`, since you said that the order of those was irrelevant.

```
filter_data = [
    {'sender_id': 1, 'receiver_id': 2, 'order': 1},
    {'sender_id': 2, 'receiver_id': 1, 'order': 3},
    {'sender_id': 3, 'receiver_id': 2, 'order': 5},
    {'sender_id': 2, 'receiver_id': 3, 'order': 2},
]

new = {}
for d in filter_data:
    total = d['sender_id'] + d['receiver_id']
    if total in new:
        if d['order'] > new[total]['order']:
            new[total] = d
    else:
        new[total] = d

print new.values()
```

For example, it will go through the first dictionary and evaluate the sum of its `receiver_id` and `sender_id` (The sum is 3). Since we have not encountered a dictionary that has `sender_id` and `receiver_id` adding up to 3 yet, it is added to our new dictionary.

However, the next dictionary also has a sum of 3. We check to see if its `order` value is greater than the previous dictionary. Since it is, it overrides that former dictionary.

Then we print the values of our new dictionary since the keys only contain the sum of `sender_id` and `receiver_id`.

Comment: There will be problems for example when i have `sender 5` and `receiver 1` and `sender 4` and `receiver 2` because they will produce same `total`

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Ah, I must have misunderstood the question then. What should happen if this happen?

Comment: You are summing values, but not combining them. What I meant was so sender 5 and receiver 1 is same as sender 1 and receiver 5(reversed values). But sender 5 and receiver 1 is not same as sender 2 and receiver 4.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Could the values for sender and receiver ever be the same?

Comment: In my case no. Because they are "chatting". But in general I don't see any difference. It should work even when `sender_id == receiver_id`